# How does multiplayer work in Divinity Original Sin?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

They say the game is "multiplayer coop". But how does the cooperation work, in details? And how many players can play the same game? I've read it can be played only by two players but it seems a bit reductive to me, I would hope it could be played by a full party (4 people or more).

Thanks in advance for any replay.

EDIT: to anyone interested, here's the link to the 4players mod: http://www.larian.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=504225

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only 2 people allowed. The host of the game controls one of the two main characters, the second player has control over the second main (wow- surprise, isn't it). So basically, host invites the other player (also possible while creating characters) and afterwards saves/loads the game, assigns additional 2 characters among players. Note that the player who joined the game is not allowed to play as long original host didn't invite them.

Comment: Thx for the replay. Sorry I don't understand what you mean with "assigns additional 2 chars among players". Have you played it in coop mode?

Comment: @think01 I have, so basically in original sin you can control up to 4 characters. Now in multiplayer, the 2 main characters the host creates, he plays the first one and the joined player plays the second. After a while people start joining your party, and then each of the players can control an extra. So for each 2. There is a mod out there that can make it so that 4 players can play each controlling one.

Comment: Thank you so much, Lyrion, sorry I cannot vote your comment so I'm going to accept this answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: You said you can invite at char creation, can the second player create the second character?

Comment: Yes. If you are playing together from the very beginning, the second player gets to create the second character.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting (which is actually a result of the correct awnser) is when you are the host and you save a game, which you load later on, the player that joined you earlier, doesn't have to be in the game when you want to continue. The character he or she occupied in your game will become AI again, until he or she will be invited again by you to join.