# How do formations work in multiplayer Divinity: Original Sin?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

There's a great [general question about multi-player in Divinity: Original Sin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/175040/11084). However, as such, the answer(s) are rather general too. My question is more specific: about the formations.

Consider this situation, where me and my friend are playing a multi-player game (in this screenshot *I*, the secondary player, have just clicked the formation icon top-left):

[image: party setup and formations]

Note that **I am the *secondary* player**, i.e. the third character from the top, controlling the fourth character (an NPC) as a follower.

The formation icons are confusing for three reasons:

- It shows *four* dots, even though I only control *two* characters (or do I?);
- The formation setup is displayed linked to the *main* character (which I do *not* control);
- My friend controls the main character, and has her *own* formation choice, which can be different from mine (but also has *four* dots).

**How do formations work, especially in multi-player games!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the "formation" is for the character(s) you're currently controlling, even though the icon *seems* attached to the first (top left most) character.

Here's an annotated version of the icon:

[image: formation square]

With this formation, when you issue a move command:

- The character you've selected will go to the spot you clicked on. This will be the **1** dot.
- All *linked* characters will fill positions 2-4, going from top to bottom on the portrait list.

If you have only 2 characters, only position 1 and 2 will be filled. See for example this move command:

[image: move command]

With this result:

[image: move result]